# CryptoJS run very slow in IE7

Tags: cryptojs

The following CryptoJs code run in normal speed in IE9 but very very slow in IE7, what is the reason behind and any method to speed up the script in IE7?

```
var keyLength = 256;  
var iteration = 1000;
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);  
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, { keySize: keyLength/32, iterations: iteration });  
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);  
var loginPassword = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
 var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(loginPassword, key, {iv:iv},{mode:CryptoJS.mode.CBC,padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has improved the speed of the JavaScript engine in IE9 to bring it up to par with other modern JS engines (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_%28JScript_engine%29)). I'm afraid there's nothing that can be done to improve the performance of the IE7 engine. Of course, in this specific case, you could reduce the number of iterations, although I am not familiar enough with PBKDF2 to say how far you can reduce it before the function becomes unsafe. Another option to consider would be moving the password hashing to the server...